# Adding Texture to only 1 face of object

Tags: faces, scale

I'm trying to add a certain texture to only 1 face of an object. However the texture appears on all sides of the object. I have looked at similar questions like this one posted in the past, but the solutions offered did not work for me. Including using the 'Assign' button.
Also, how do I change the scale of the texture using the nodes in the Shading section. I can't find the right node that would alter the scaling of the texture.[image][image]

Comment: You have to make two material slots and select the face in the edit mode a click assign button so the selected material will be assigned only to selected face

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to adjust the scaling of the texture in Shading section?

Comment: To scale the texture, you need to add the Mapping node (Vector -> Mapping) to the node tree. Connect it to the vector input on the image texture node. Also, make sure you have a Texture Coordinate node (Input -> Texture Coordinate), in the tree, and add that to the top vector input in the mapping node. You can probably use "Generated" and it will work fine. You can also use the shortcut ctrl+t (with your main shader selected) to automatically add those nodes.

Comment: I followed your suggestion but the texture was no longer visible. Here is link of the screenshot. I circled the node connection where the problem might be ... perhaps. https://www.mediafire.com/view/smi542ja9vyf03x/scale.PNG/file